# Finding in a list that contains an attribute of an object

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find which items in my list fill a certain criteria.

I have a `List<Employee>`, and each `Employee` has a `List<Role>` attribute. Each `Role` has an `ID` as an attribute. I'm trying to find all `Employee`s that have a certain `Role ID` in the list. Here is my non-working sample:

```
var query = EmployeeList.Where(employee=> employee.Roles.Contains(role => role.ID == roleID)).ToList();
```

Comment: In addition to given answers: [List<T>.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) does not accept predicate. It accepts an element of type `T` and uses element's type `IEquatable<T>.Equals` implementation.

Comment: You might consider using a HashSet<T> of role ids, instead of the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)

```
var query = EmployeeList.Where(employee => employee.Roles
                                                   .Any(role => role.Id == roleID))
                                                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just change your `Contains` to `Any` (as you're just checking whether *any* of the roles of the employee matches your condition):

```
var query = EmployeeList.Where(employee => employee.Roles
                                                 .Any(role => role.ID == roleID))
                        .ToList();
```

Note that this won't be a terribly efficient approach - every employee has to be checked, and every role of every employee. If you need to do this often with the same set of employees but different role IDs, you could build a lookup from role ID to employees:

```
var lookup = EmployeeList.SelectMany(e => e.Roles,
                                     (e, r) => new { Employee = e, Role = e })
                         .ToLookup(pair => pair.Role.ID,
                                   pair => pair.Employee);
```

You can then just use:

```
foreach (var employee in lookup[roleID])
{
    ....
}
```